# How can I implement "no match found" in search filter pipe in angular2?

Tags: angular

Hi how can I implement no match found in search filter pipe in angular2?  I want a text "No item found" in case of not match found .
Thanks

```html
 transform(flightlist: FlightModel[], text: any): any {
        if (!text) {
            return flightlist;
        }

        return flightlist.filter((it) => {
            return it.arrivalModel.city.includes(text) || it.arrivalModel.fs.includes(text) || it.departure.includes(text) || it.arrival.includes(text) || it.departureModel.city.includes(text);
        })

    }
```

Comment: can you share your code with the community so we can help you furthermore? that would be helpful

Comment: transform(flightlist: FlightModel[], text: any): any {
        if (!text) {
            return flightlist;
        }

        return flightlist.filter((it) => {
            return it.arrivalModel.city.includes(text) || it.arrivalModel.fs.includes(text) || it.departure.includes(text) || it.arrival.includes(text) || it.departureModel.city.includes(text);
        })

    }

Comment: please add the code to your question

Comment: https://netbasal.com/using-pipe-results-in-angular-templates-430683fa2213

Comment: example is similar to my work but I can't handle when text written in input is not included in array. If text is not included in a array, I'd like a text "no item found" in html. Ho can I handle it in pipe? Thanks

Comment: you can use the example and implement as per your need

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check to your filtered list to see if it is populated, instead of returning the raw filtered list.

```
transform(flightlist: FlightModel[], text: any): any {
    if (!text) {
        return flightlist;
    }

    const filtered = flightlist.filter((it) => {
        return it.arrivalModel.city.includes(text) || 
               it.arrivalModel.fs.includes(text) || 
               it.departure.includes(text) || 
               it.arrival.includes(text) || 
               it.departureModel.city.includes(text);
    });

    if (filtered.length === 0) { 
        filtered.push("No item found" as any); 
        return filtered; 
    } 

    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Sorrry but idt doesn't work. I don't see any string no item found in the template when filtered===[]

Comment: if (filtered.length === 0) {
            filtered.push("No item" as any);
            return filtered;
        }    
        else {
            console.log("item")
            return filtered;
        }        It works!!

Comment: glad to hear you got it working. I updated my code to reflect what worked for you